# Problems connecting to the database - Sql Server and Visual Studio C#

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server, c#, wpf

I have encountered problems connecting to the sql server by visual studio with Entity Framework 6. My connection worked normally and after I created a new project, I can not access the database server.
The service works normally.
[Sql Service Services](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejyHq.png)

My connection string is always giving error stating that the **Initial Catalog** keyword is not supported. I have already removed this parameter and realized that everything that is after **Data Source** is considered as an unsupported keyword.

> public DataContext() : base("Data Source=localhost/sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=DocManager;User Id=sa;Password=123456; Integrated Security=false;")
>           {

```
    }
```

Firewall is disabled to prevent port-locking problems.

[Firewall Inative](https://i.stack.imgur.com/haJck.png)

As an alternative I tried to make the connection through the server manager tool of Visual Studio itself, but to my disappointment, I can not make any connection from there and my server is not listed for connection.
[Service manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DrYp.png)

Any suggestions that can help me solve this problem?

Comment: Looks like you might be loading the wrong provider.  You’ll need to post more code and the full Exception stack trace to be sure.

Comment: can you login with sa user to ssms? put your exception here.

Comment: 1 - Keyword not supported: 'initial catalog'.

2 - Erro de rede ou específico à instância ao estabelecer conexão com o SQL Server. O servidor não foi encontrado ou não estava acessível. Verifique se o nome da instância está correto e se o SQL Server está configurado para permitir conexões remotas. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Não foi possível abrir uma conexão com o SQL Server)